# Setting Holo theme for Android application

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a simple login screen with username and password.

I'd like it to show the `EditText` fields in the same way as you see in the Holo theme on Ice Cream Sandwich and Honeycomb.

In my manifest file I have

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
```

Shouldn't the text fields now look different e.g. have no top, left and right borders?

Mine seem to look the exact same. I'm sure I'm doing something very basically wrong but any suggestions welcome.

This is what I see in the emulator:
[image: Screen Shot 2012-04-23 at 03.08.16]

I was expecting more like this:
http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/text-fields.html

Comment: What android version is the emulator running? You'll only get Holo in 3.0 +

Comment: http://cl.ly/1j3z080V0F1N2c1Z421U < yes this and I run on real device with ICS

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The original Android Holo Theme is just for API Level 11+. But there is an open source project called HoloEverywhere.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere). This should solve your Problems.

So if you refere it as an Library you can set your Theme like this:

```
android:theme=“@style/Theme.Holo
// or if you want to use the Holo light theme:
android:theme=“@style/Theme.Holo.Light
```

Comment: In truth I restarted eclipse and it just worked but thanks for extra info.

Comment: Link broken but this appears to be the new location: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Comment: A note for the newer versions of HoloEverywhere, the theme you must use now is `@style/Holo.Theme.*`

Answer (score 9):

Try doing it on a per-activity basis.  That's how I've always done it.  It looks to me like the theme is not taking effect at all in your screenshot.  Theme.Holo is dark.  The white theme is Theme.Holo.Light.

```
<activity
        android:name=".login"
        android:label="@string/login"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>

<activity
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
```

etc rather than in the app level

Also, to correct Ahmad, Holo is available from Honeycomb and on, or 11+.

Comment: Eclipse says that it will only work from 13+ not 11+

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Holo is available since API 11; it's just `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` that came in API level 14. There is no need for 15+.

For older API Levels, `HoloEverywhere`, `ActionBarSherlock`, `ViewPageIndicator` and such are neccessary, as mentioned by Ahmad as well.

Comment: duplicates Ahmad's answer