# DataPicker looks like old design on new API's as well

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

So the problem is very simple:

I have integrated a `DatePicker` in my application.
Not as a `DialogDatePicker` but as a View component (more precisely a `View` inside of a `Fragment` that is dynamically shown and removed from a `FrameLayout` contained in my main `FragmentActiviy` layout.).

now my problem is that this DataPicker looks like this:
[image]

and not like this:

[image]

even when I target the higher API's, I tried setting my Min SDK to 16 or 17 as well but it didn't do any help either.

Some one know why it happens? and how can I show the new look of the data picker?
preferably on old versions of Android as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** code:

**DataPickerFragment xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6.5dp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="8.5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8.5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/date_picker_background">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:onClick="buttonCanceDatePickerOnclick"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSave"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:onClick="buttonSaveDatePickerOnclick"
            android:text="@string/save" />

     </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**DataPickerFramgnet class:**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button bSave, bCancel;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker_fragment_layout, 
                                         container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**Manifast file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.emildesign.sgreportmanager"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!--  Crittercism  -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.SGRaportManagerAppObj"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <activity
            android:name="com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.activities.LoginScrActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.activities.ReportsTableActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.emildesign.sgreportmanager.activities.ParametersActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.crittercism.NotificationActivity"/>  
</application>
```

well I found where my problem was, I set:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to make my application full screen and this applied the old style of the data picker changing it to:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Creates the following DataPicker:

[image]

It's better then before but this is still not the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Where are you seeing that set date dialog?

Comment: @Ian Carroll, didn't understood your question.

Comment: @EmilAdz Hi I'm facing the same problem,is it possible to keep the same theme as well as use new date picker, as my whole project is based on the main theme and i don't want any changes,i also tried by specifying the Theme.Light for particular activity but it changes the theme of alert dialog instead date picker,please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to be 11 or higher. [Here is a sample application demonstrating this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/DatePicker).

---

**UPDATE**

First, your original `DatePicker` screenshot is from a dark theme (e.g., `Theme.Holo`), whereas your second screenshot is from a light theme (e.g., `Theme.Holo.Light`).

Second, the `DatePicker` documentation has the following opening paragraph:

> This class is a widget for selecting a date. The date can be selected by a year, month, and day spinners or a CalendarView. The set of spinners and the calendar view are automatically synchronized. The client can customize whether only the spinners, or only the calendar view, or both to be displayed. Also the minimal and maximal date from which dates to be selected can be customized.

You can get rid of the `CalendarView` via `android:calendarViewShown` (or `setCalendarViewShown()`). When you try that, you will find that your year spinner will appear once the `CalendarView` is gone.

Comment: @EmilAdz: I suspect that you are setting your build target to be 17 but not setting `android:targetSdkVersion` to 11 or higher. The build target and the `android:targetSdkVersion` are independent concepts.

Comment: @EmilAdz: Please see update in answer. Please try running the sample app I linked to in that answer to see this in action.

Comment: I will try those methods, I think that you are right. 2 qustions: 
1. how can I download the project from git using the browser(is there a way?)
2. is there any way that I could use this DatePicker on older version of android?

Comment: @EmilAdz: "how can I download the project from git using the browser(is there a way?)" -- you can go to the repo's main page (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) and click the ZIP button to download the entire repo. "is there any way that I could use this DatePicker on older version of android?" -- IMHO, that's a bad idea, and I do not know of an option for that anyway. IMHO, use the picker that the user will be used to for their device.

Comment: yeah just found this zip button. last question and I am accepting you answer as it was most helpful to me: if I am targeting API 11 and above (strangely eclipse tells me that so i could use Theme.Holo i need to target API 13), is there a way to change the color of the blue separator and the text, and change the text size?

Comment: @EmilAdz: Probably, though I have not tried to theme a `DatePicker` and therefore do not have specific guidance for you. You might consider opening up a fresh StackOverflow question to try to get an answer. Sorry!

Comment: Yes I will do that. @CommonsWare, Thanks you were very helpful to me. Your question is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the Holo theme.

So, your theme should look like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: is it possibly this style only to the DataPicker?

Comment: @EmilAdz You could create a new activity to wrap the DatePicker and set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` in your AndroidManifest.xml only in that activity's section. I just tested it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

*Answering to your update*

Change

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`

to

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`

Comment: yeah I have already understood that, but question is there a way to use the same DatePicker in the older versions? and is there a way to edit how this DatePicker looks, I need to change the blue lines to white and change the text color? is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe you can make this theme appear on older versions of Android. If I understand everything correctly, the theme itself is a part of OS, all the drawables, colors, margins, widget, all the look and feel, all of it is stored in OS, not in your app. Your app basically tells the OS "Draw this dialog in Theme.Holo!". And older versions of Android simply don't have that theme, so they can't draw it.

Comment: @EmilAdz Actually I just checked and technically it can be done, but you would have to bundle all the theme's resources with your app. Take a look at these two questions and their answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649634/set-holo-theme-in-older-android-versions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274015/setting-holo-theme-for-android-application

Comment: I will check this option out. Thanks Anton do you know if there is a way to edit the new DataPicker looks: change the blue lines to white and change the text color??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet for calling device's default Date And Time Picker

date_time_layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:calendarViewShown="false" > <!-- style="@style/date_picker_style" -->
            </DatePicker>

            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TimePicker>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialogCancel"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Cancel" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialogSet"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Set" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Put this method in your class and call it using showDateAndTimePicker();

```
private void showDateAndTimePicker() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,
                android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.date_time_layout);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setTitle("Select Date and Time");
        Button set = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogSet);
        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogCancel);
        final DatePicker dtp = (DatePicker) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        final TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Handle Set button
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Handle Cancel button
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
```