# how to achive this Edittext bottom line shape in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i tried using shape in android,
inset in android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
</shape>
```

bt i want like below image type  edittext

[how to achieve dis...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keGL8.png)

what i use to create this edittext,
shape,
inset
...
please help me out ...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is EditText style in android Holo theme. You can go down to the lower version to achive this. Or the easiest way is use this library: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Hope this help :)

Comment: Yeh you can simply change theme on your project. Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274015/setting-holo-theme-for-android-application

Answer (score 0):

This may sound tedious but, one of the ways is to put official drawables in your project. The site: http://android-holo-colors.com/ will help you generate exactly the drawables you need and then you can put them in their respective `drawable` folders. Once, you've done that you simply set them as background in your `EditText`.

If you want to change color, you can use `setColorFilter()` on these drawables before using them as backgrounds.